# How to disable WIFI in Python 3? (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, wifi

I'm making a python script that should turn off the WIFI on windows.
I've tried searching on google, but all I could find is to disconnect from a specific WIFI. And that's not what I want, Because if you on another computer and you run the same script, it probably wont turn off your WIFI because you don't have the same WIFI as the person who wrote the script.

So does anybody knows how I can make a python script that will disable\turn off the WIFI on the computer and work with every WIFI without changing the script?

Answer (score 0):

Often, high-level programming language don't have access to system settings. Hence you could **import the os module** and send out some signal to notify the operating system to switch off the Wifi.

```
os.system()
```

you are using Window. you could fill the function with this

```
netsh interface set interface 'Wifi' disabled
```

For those using OS X, you could fill the function with this

```
sudo networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled Wi-Fi off
```

Comment: I'm on windows. I said I need something to work with every windows computer, but in the command I need to fill my Wifi. So it wont work on every windows computer because I will have to edit the script every time!

Comment: @FlafyMation You will need to have your script programmatically find the Wifi adapter and disable it, there is no universal way to turn off wifi for any computer.

Comment: @Josh Weinstein Oh ok. But how do I get the string I need to fill in there?

Comment: @FlafyMation  Ok Now I get what you mea,   you mean you want the script to fill in the wifi interface name automatically right?        you can make use of the command      "netsh wlan show interfaces"    that will pop up all the names of wifi adaptor,   and then you extract it in python,    and using python to execute the final command

Comment: @JoshWeinstein Well. I have this code to get the Interfaces `os.system("netsh interface show interface")` but I don't know how to get what it prints.

Comment: @FlafyMation As noted in my own answer, you need to use the `subprocess` module, as those capture the `stdout` of running a child process.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to reliably do this for *any* computer and *any* wifi. Every computer has a different wifi adapter which may be placed differently in the win32 network api.

What you can do is, execute system commands for command prompt, to query and find the current system's wifi adapter. For example, in order to find the wifi adapter, you could use the following

```
 wmic nic get name, index
```

This will show you a list of adapters. If one of them says something at the end like `WiFi Adapter`, you can use the index of that entry with the following command:

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable
```

This turns the wifi off. Keep in mind this may work or not work on different versions of Windows. This also may not work if the Windows user is not using command prompt when running your python script.

To call these commands from Python, use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html) module. You can run commands there with the `run()` or `check_output()` methods:

```
>>> subprocess.run(["dir", "C:\users"], capture_output=True)
```